# Hibernate generating incorrect DDL for H2 in tests. Springboot 3.2.2, Hibernate 6.4.1, H2 2.2.224

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I am upgrading from Spring 2.X (Java 8) to Spring 3.2.2 / Java 17
Snippet from my Entity definition:

```
  @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(1 CHAR) DEFAULT 'N'")
  private Boolean checkFlag;

  @Column(length = 64)
  private String randomKey;
```

In production we use Oracle, so columnDefinition has "CHAR(1 CHAR)"

In test cases, DDL generated for H2 is as follows:
`checkFlag CHAR(1 CHAR) DEFAULT 'N'`,

Problem is H2 is not honoring CHAR(1 CHAR), it expects CHAR(1)

I tried setting various Mode in H2 URL: like Oracle, Legacy. Nothing helps.
This used to work in Springboot 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If custom column definition is specified in the annotation, JPA uses it as is, correctness of this definition is under your responsibility.

The simplest solution here is to use `CHAR` instead of non-standard `CHAR(1 CHAR)`, because 1 is the default anyway.

H2 is able to parse Oracle-specific length too, but only in the Oracle compatibility mode, in other modes only standard length specification is allowed. To pass custom settings to H2 you need to disable automatic configuration of JDBC URL for unit tests with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE` or in any other way, otherwise your custom JDBC URL with these settings will be ignored.

Comment: H2 URL is set to 
jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle; 
Strange thing is it was working in older version of Java/Spring Boot/Hibernate. I am running into this issue only after upgrade

Comment: There are many similar questions here, with newer versions it isn't enough and you have to disable auto-configuration of this URL explicitly.

Comment: We took your suggestion and it solved the issue we removed column definitions